# Problems with JavaScript calculator

Tags: javascript, html, calculator

I'm making this calculator and have no idea why nothing comes into `tulos` box. Here is the code, I hope someone can help me. I'm starter with these kind of things, so there might be some really big mistakes in code.

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Laskurit</title>
</head>

<body>

<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
function Laskin() {

var paino = document.korvaus.paino.value; 
var hinta = document.korvaus.hinta.value;
var mista = document.korvaus.mista.value;
var tulos;




if (mista == "koti")
{
 paino *= 20 == koti1;
 
 if (koti1 >= hinta)
 {
  tulos = hinta;
 }
 else
 {
  tulos = koti1;
 }
}
else if (mista == "ulko")
{
 paino *= 9,75 == ulko1;
 
 if (ulko1 >= hinta)
 {
  tulos = hinta;
 }
 else
 {
  tulos = ulko1;
 }
}

document.korvaus.tulos.value = tulos;

}
-->
</script> 

<p><b>Korvauslaskuri</b></p>
<form name="korvaus">
<table><tr><td>Paino: <td><input type="text" name="paino"><br>
<tr><td>Kokonaishinta(€): <td><input type="text" name"hinta"><br>
<tr><td>Mistä/mihin?<br>
<td><select name="mista">
            <option value="koti">Kotimaa</option>
            <option value="ulko">Ulkomaa</option>
        </select> 
<tr><td>
  <p>Korvausmäärä(€):</p>
    <td><p><input type="text" size="40" name="tulos"></p>

</table></form>
<form name="nappulalomake">
    <p><input type="button" name="B1" value="Laske" onClick="Laskin()"></p>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You tagged the question with the Java tag. The code in the question body implies JavaScript/HTML. Please balance the question.

Comment: Also, non-finnish variable names greatly improve readability.

Comment: I don't think your `paino *= ...."` statements are correct. Double check those.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you are trying to accomplish but there were a few syntax errors in your code.  Here working code

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Laskurit</title>
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
function Laskin() {

var paino = document.korvaus.paino.value; 
var hinta = document.korvaus.hinta.value;
var mista = document.korvaus.mista.value;
var tulos;




if (mista == "koti")
{
 var koti1 = paino *20;
 
 if (koti1 >= hinta)
 {
  tulos = hinta;
 }
 else
 {
  tulos = koti1;
 }
}
else if (mista == "ulko")
{
 var ulko1 = paino *9.75;
 
 if (ulko1 >= hinta)
 {
  tulos = hinta;
 }
 else
 {
  tulos = ulko1;
 }
}

document.korvaus.tulos.value = tulos;

}
-->
</script> 
</head>

<body>



<p><b>Korvauslaskuri</b></p>
<form name="korvaus">
<table border=0>
<tr><td>Paino: </TD><td><input type="text" name="paino"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Kokonaishinta(€):</tD><td><input type="text" name="hinta"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Mistä/mihin?</td><td><select name="mista">
            <option value="koti">Kotimaa</option>
            <option value="ulko">Ulkomaa</option>
        </select> 
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
  <p>Korvausmäärä(€):</p></td>
    <td><p><input type="text" size="40" name="tulos"></p></td>
</tr>

</table></form>
<form name="nappulalomake">
    <p><input type="button" name="B1" value="Laske" onClick="Laskin()"></p>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```